# Lie algebra action and universal enveloping algebra

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a finite-dimensional Lie algebra over the complex numbers with an invariant symmetric bilinear form $( \enspace, \enspace )$. Let $e_1, \dotsc, e_n$ be an orthogonal basis with respect to this bilinear form.

1. For $w = \sum_{i=1}^n e_i \otimes e_i \in \mathfrak{g} \otimes \mathfrak{g}$, how can I show that it is invariant under the $\mathfrak{g}$-action?  
   Attempt: I think I have to show $h \cdot w = 0$ for $h \in \mathfrak{g}$ and use $h \cdot (a \otimes b) = (h \cdot a) \otimes b + a \otimes (h \cdot b)$, but I don't know how to apply the orthogonality exactly.
2. How can I prove that the universal enveloping algebra $U(\mathfrak{g})$ is a representation of the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ under the action $h \cdot u = hu - uh$ for $h \in \mathfrak{g}$, $u \in U(\mathfrak{g})$.

Comment: For 2, what is your definition of $U(g)$? And you must have a definition of what a $g$-representation, so there's a finite list of equations to check ... which of them gives you trouble?

Comment: For 1, I would write out your general element $h$ in that basis $e_1,..., e_n$. And then hope the invariance of the bilinear form and orthogonality of the $e_i$ shows that everything cancels out. For starters, I would try to write it down for $n=2$ or $3$ and hope that I see a pattern.